# Unable to select model via gui if scan overlaps

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unable to select model via gui if scan wash overlaps the model. The only way to select the model is via the world model tab in this case. Does graphic software support layers that allow pass through cursor selection?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4168/unable-to-select-model-via-gui-if-scan-overlaps/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This has recently been [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/709/fix-mouse-picking-for-cases-where-visuals/diff)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0